# Background image not appearing in converted html to pdf

Tags: html, css, api, background-image, convertapi

I am having issues getting a background image to work using your conversion api.
Eg of the template file styling:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="https://use.typekit.net/mmg2zqw.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body, p, li, td, th, dt, dd { font-family: arboria, sans-serif, arial, helvetica; font-weight: 300; font-style: normal; font-size:20px; color:#333; }
    body { background: url(/templates/backgrounds/certificate-background.png) no-repeat; }
    img { border:none; display:block; }
    p { margin-top:0; font-size: 20px;}
    span { margin-top:0; font-size: 24px; color: #78BE21;}
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 { font-family: arboria, sans-serif, arial, helvetica; font-weight: 300; font-style: normal; color:#555; }

    h1 { font-size:68px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 20px; }
    h2 { font-size:52px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #78BE21; }
    h3 { font-size:30px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 5px; }
    h4 { font-size:18px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 0; }
    h5 { font-size:14px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Do I need to add a parameter to the api call to allow the image to work?

Comment: Please provide a html example to reproduce an issue. Thank you.

Comment: Here is an example https://dev.gbca.org.au/import/54-membership-2906202025.htm

Answer (score -1):

You are thinkting to put a minimum height to see a possible change ? Beacause if your tag contains nothing, so your background will not be visible.

**Try this on your body :**

```
body { 
  background-image: url('/templates/backgrounds/certificate-background.png') no-repeat;
  width: 100%
  min-heigth: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatley, did not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ensure you use the full path to the image.